# CPU is fixed at 100% usage

Tags: cpu, virus, temperature, resource-monitor, resource-usage

I would like to start by saying that I'm aware that there are a lot of questions with the same title but I would like to say that they are very specific to their own problem. Unfortunately my problem is most likely also unique but its still a problem nonetheless.

Like I stated in the title, my CPU is fixed at 100% (and way higher).

Screenshot of taskmanager:

[image: http://prntscr.com/a1xcus]

Screenshot of Resource Monitor: (**Note the CPU usage!**)

[image]

Now the resource monitor made me laugh but also made me very worried.

Next thing I did was check my temperatures. (I run a stock I5-2500K with watercooling (which is overkill but I just picked up some watercooling to have the possibility of overclocking in the future)).

Screenshot of temperatures:

[image: http://prntscr.com/a1xjxt]

So overheating is not an issue and as far as I know its never been an issue. So I personally excluded hardware failure (due to overheating) as a possible cause.

Next thing was checking for viruses or any malware infection.

Screenshot of scan results:

[image]

Nothing interesting there (running a full scan right now but I doubt that will result in anything).

---

**TLDR**

- CPU running at 100%
- Temperatures are fine
- No viruses

---

If anyone has any idea about what might be causing my CPU to be constantly at 100% feel free to share.

---

### **EDIT**

You can see all my specs with most setting [HERE](http://valid.x86.fr/xliwmm)

Comment: What speed does your machine report the CPU is running at? You may need something like CPU-Z to get an accurate reading.

Comment: Your RAM could be overheating, but it's not that likely.

Comment: @Jonno the speed varies a lot switching between 1500 MHz and 3600MHz : http://prntscr.com/a1z155

Comment: Some suggestions in the comments here...http://superuser.com/questions/1009490/windows-10-upgrade-has-100-cpu-usage-on-startup

Comment: may be it's speedstep at work? So CPU underclocks itself. Can you check clock speed in CPU-Z when CPU is maxed  out without any load?