# Why am I seeing 100% CPU usage from mundane tasks on Windows 10?

Tags: cpu, performance, cpu-usage, overheating

I have a problem when my CPU raises to 100% usage from mundane tasks that normally take less than 1% of CPU for a few minutes. This is how it looks like:

[image: CPU usage at 100%]

Now it is true that the Antimalware can take some CPU, but the other apps never take more than 1 or 2%, and definetely not for several minutes in a row, so something else has to be going on than 6 apps bugging out at the exact same time.

This seems to happen at random times, sometimes when I start up a game (but continues even when I close the game for a few minutes), and even as I am writing this very question, so I took 2 screenshots for comparison:

High usage during the "lag": (here I lost the screenshot with the "Processes" tab, but it looked similar to the first screenshot, random apps like Discord or Firefox taking 10% or more while normally they take less than 1%, as you will see in the next screenshot).
[image: High CPU usage]

Normal usage taken 1 minute later:
[image: Low CPU usage]

Now, it might be that the CPU is simply overheated and needs to cool down. But why is power usage going up, rising from 26W to 68W? Wouldn't the power usage go down in order to cool the processor?

Full specs:

- OS: Windows 10 64-bit Pro
- Motherboard: Z370-A PRO (MS-7B48)
- Processor: Intel i7-8700 @ 3.20GHz (12
  CPUs)
- Memory: 4x 8GB DDR5 RAM
- Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080

I have tried looking at [CPU is fixed at 100% usage](https://superuser.com/questions/1038616/cpu-is-fixed-at-100-usage) and [Windows 10 Upgrade has 100% Cpu Usage on startup](https://superuser.com/questions/1009490/windows-10-upgrade-has-100-cpu-usage-on-startup) but with no success.

Comment: Run: `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` leave it for say 1 minute when you have the issue and then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\gp.etl`.  The gp.etl, will then need to be analyzed in WPA (Windows Performance Analyzer) that you can get from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Thanks. I already bought and installed a new CPU fan, and it seems to be working fine.